# What is the earliest that the shunned guardian motif appears?

Tags: history-of, the-witcher

I would like to know what is the earliest work using what I call the *shunned guardian* motif.

What I mean by *shunned guardian* is a character (or organization) which guards the society from some external threat (usually monsters), but is himself shunned by that society.

Two modern examples I know of are claymores from the manga series [Claymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claymore_(manga)) and witchers (come to think of, both slay the monsters for money, ruinous amounts of it in Claymore).

Editing in a clarification from comments: the society is aware of the danger. It may have low probability or not be imminent, but they are aware of it.

Comment: To be clear, what you're talking about is cases where society at large _is aware_ of the dangers, which makes this different from [the Masquerade](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Masquerade)?

Comment: Asking for a list of works that contain X element is off-topic, so I would suggest editing that out. The actual question asked in the body - which doesn't mention the "What works?" part - is fine.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: @DavidW yes, they are aware - but the danger might not be imminent or have a relatively low probability. Like the regular Yoma in Claymore - they appear rarely and then usually only eat a single person a day from the whole town. The people are terrified when this happens but then tend to forget quickly.

Comment: Eomer from Lord of the Rings; The Two Towers *might* fight. Less shunned by the entire society and more by the current government, but still - he's on the outs by and large and still doing his best to protect the society

Comment: @NKCampbell no, unless the politics influence the society I wouldn't consider this a fit. Otherwise I would probably mentioned Grey Wardens from Dragon Age in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One obvious example are the [Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rangers_of_the_North), the descendants of the northern kingdom of Numenoreans, who by the third age guard and watch over places like the Shire and Bree and are clearly shunned and misunderstood by Hobbits and Men alike.

A possible ancient example are the [Fianna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fianna) of Ireland (best known from the Fenian Cycle). These were landless aristocrats who spent the winter among society, but spent the summer "shunned" and foraging and fending for themselves.

Another possibility that comes to mind is [Enkidu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh). Once created, he shuns civilisation and lives among the wild animals. He himself is shunned by civilised society though he eventually becomes the friend & guardian of Gilgamesh with whom a very great friendship evolves.

Comment: +1 but let me wait for other answers. You reminded me that we had something loosely similar to Fianna in Poland in the XVIII century. Basically poor nobles who worked their fields themselves, while being obliged by law to defend the country.

Comment: Obligatory: "Darmok and Jalaad at Tanagra. Enkidu! A wild man...."